# Modernizr: export detected features list

Tags: javascript, modernizr

I would like to know exactly what features are available in a custom Webkit and put that in a human-readable document for my client.

Modernizr seems the way to go, but I was wondering if there is a way to easily export the detected features list to a readable document (csv, html, text) ?

Comment: Have you tried JSON.stringify-ing the Modernizr object?

Comment: I was looking for a tool that would do that for me, but I couldn't find one so I guess I'll do something like that.